# disable button type cancel validation

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code using bootstrap

```
<input name="mail" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>

<button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary">rechercher</button>
<button type="cancel" class="cancel btn btn-warning" disableValidation="true">annuler</button>
```

When I click on cancel to reset the form it shows me the error on the email input :
"please fill this field"

I don't understand why a button with type cancel is making a validation process and how to disable it without adding uselesss javascript ?

Comment: remove class `btn-warning`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset button type should be "reset" instead of "cancel"

Comment: thanks a lot, I knew the answer would be so easy but didn't made front since a while...